# What modulation is this?

Tags: radio

[image: screenshot of the wave]

[image: signal more detail]

I'm currently learning about signal modulation and fail to figure out the modulation of this signal - maybe someone can help me with it?

The software is GNURadio and the device capturing the signal is a bladeRF SDR. The device producing it is a remote control for home automation. A button was pressed to produce the signal. I'll try adding a new screenshot showing the signal in more detail. the documentation for GNURadio is here: gnuradio.org/docs

I would assume it's ASK, maybe with Manchester encoding. But what makes no sense to me are the long zeros with the small ones.

[image: audacity screenshot]

[image: gnuradio graph for audacity screenshot]

[image: detail view of signal sample]

Comment: Thanks John - can I move it myself? I can't find an option.

Comment: Click the *flag* link and choose the *in need of moderator intervention* option. Leave a message for the mods asking if they would migrate it for you.

Comment: As an EE.SE regular, I'll say there's not enough information here to answer the question. What is producing the signal? What else do you know about it besides the presented chart? Can you make a plot zooming in on one of the signal bursts with enough detail to show the signal in detail?

Comment: Also, what is the software being used to present the plot? Where can we find its documentation?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The software is GNURadio and the device capturing the signal is a bladeRF SDR. The device producing it is a remote control for home automation. A button was pressed to produce the signal. I'll try adding a new screenshot showing the signal in more detail. the documentation for GNURadio is here: https://www.gnuradio.org/docs/

Comment: I would assume it's ASK, maybe with Manchester encoding. But what makes no sense to me are the long zeros with the small ones.

Comment: @Omegavirus: long periods when the thing is not transmitting reduce power consumption, which is an issue for remote controls.

Comment: It looks like OOK, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks, I assume so too. But how can I get the 0's and 1's out of it?

Comment: Could be something like a 10 us burst for 0, 20 us burst for 1 (or vice versa)

Comment: @ThePhoton I've added a screenshot showing a snippet of the signal from audacity in more detail. There are longer highs and shorter highs, but the lows are always a lot longer.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the intervals between bursts are irrelevant (except to establish the bit rate), and the length of the burst is what determines a 0 or 1.

Comment: Not much of a person that knows a whole lot about shift keying but the 1s and 0s would be determined  by your digital data that's being carried by the carrier signal. You would mix both the digital information coming in and the carrier signal. Depending on your digital logic and the frequency of your carrier signal, that's what will determine the 1s and 0s of the ASK/OOK signal.

Comment: @KingDuken, "shift keying" is more or less just another word for "[digital] modulation". Phase shift keying means adjusting phase to indicate 1 or 0. Amplitude shift keying means adjusting amplitude to indicate a 1 or 0. So they're just synonyms for "digital phase modulation" and "digital amplitude modulation".

Comment: @ThePhoton Now I get your point, that sounds possible. Do you know a handy way to extract the data via GNURadio blocks?

Comment: @Omegavirus, my knowledge of GNURadio is more or less limited to how to spell "GNURadio".

Comment: @ThePhoton Ok, no problem, I'll try to look it up. Do you know if that way of sending data has a special name or nomenclature?

Comment: You could call it pulse width modulation, but that term is more often used for systems where the message signal is analog.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by an asked who never provided the information needed to make it answerable

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a kind of low duty cycle *pulse width modulation*.

A "short" burst of ~10 us indicates a 0, and a "long" burst of ~20 us represents a 1 (or possibly vice versa).

The long intervals between bursts, giving only ~5 bit per second overall data rate, serve to minimize the system power consumption.

Comment: Having reversed a lot of OOK protocols, chances are it is not really a low data rate, but rather that we aren't seeing an accurate representation of the parts of the signal where the actual data is

Comment: @ChrisStratton what would you need to determine the signal type in more detail? Would a wav or raw recording of the signal be of any help?

Comment: Your problem may in essence be zooming in on the wrong parts.  Try running a histogram of all of the "high" (signal present) durations and also all of the "low" ones.  Typically you see preambles, data, and gaps between repetitions.